# Round minutes to hours and quarters of hours (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, date

I have a total of minutes and I am trying to convert these minutes in hours and quarters of hours, for instance:

```
513 minutes / 60 = 8.55 -> so would be 8.3 hours
485 minutes / 60 = 8.083 -> 8 hours
```

How can I do this using SQL?

I have been searching and what I found was this, but doesn't work for me:

`@mins` is the variable where I am storing the minutes.

```
set @mins = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,@mins) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I don't understand your first example, isn't 0.55 hours only 2 quarters?

Comment: This feels like an *really* odd requirement and probabyl is the beginnings of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Tip: The explanation "doesn't work for me" isn't a particularly specific problem description. Perhaps it's related to the data type of `@mins` which you have strategically omitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that you can't have times that are 24 or more hours, you could do something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR,T.[Time]),'.',DATEPART(MINUTE,T.[Time]) /10)
FROM (VALUES(513),(485),(107))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE, YourColumn, CONVERT(time(0),'00:00')))) T([Time]);
```

But, like I mention in my comment under the question, this feels like the beginnings of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do what you want, rounding down to the nearest 15 minutes and then treating that as "decimal" hours:

```
select mins / 60 + (((mins % 60)) / 15) * 0.15
from (values (513), (485)) v(mins)
```

Using a number to represent the minutes is really misleading and likely to result in errors downstream, when `8.3` is interpreted as 8.3 hours -- which is 498 minutes.

I would strongly encourage you to represent the value as a proper `time` value.  You can generate that using:

```
timefromparts(mins / 60, (((mins % 60)) / 15) * 15, 0, 0, 0)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4885ddc057ba2edaebe734edd3d44b81) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MinutesTotal   int
DECLARE @QuatersTotal   int
DECLARE @HoursOut       int
DECLARE @QuatersOut     numeric(10,2)

SET @MinutesTotal   =   
                --      513 --  8:30 
                --      485 --  8:00 
                        166 --  2:45    

SET @QuatersTotal   =   @MinutesTotal / 15                          
SET @HoursOut       =   @QuatersTotal /  4                          
SET @QuatersOut     =   (@QuatersTotal - (@HoursOut * 4)) * 15



DECLARE @ResultTime time = '00:00'

SET     @ResultTime = DATEADD(HOUR  , @HoursOut     , @ResultTime)
SET     @ResultTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, @QuatersOut   , @ResultTime)

SELECT  
        @ResultTime 
    ,   ResultAsString  =   CONVERT(varchar(5), @ResultTime )
    ,   ResultAsDecimal =   @HoursOut + (@QuatersOut / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want this arithmetics:

```
select @min / 60 + @min % 60 / 100.0
```

This gives you the number of hours as an integer, followed by the remaining number of minutes in the decimal part, so for your sample data this yields `8.33` and `8.05` respectively.

On the other hand, if you want the decimal part to represents the number of quarters of hours, then:

```
select @min / 60 + @min % 60 / 15 / 10.0
```

This produces `8.2` and `8.0`.